# Logging custom action event Liferay - user add + delete

Tags: java, jsp, liferay-6, custom-action, portal

Does anybody know how can I log to a file the creation/deletion event for an user in Liferay 6.2? Is there any 'listener' that I must watch for or any action (struts action) that can be overwritten to achieve this?

I successfully used a hook to log the login and logout events, using [custom action](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/performing-a-custom-action-using-a-hook) and [portal properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html).

If anybody knows a way to log certain events (e.g. adding user to an usergroup or something similar) using custom code (maybe JSP), please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be helpful
Its a tutorial to override liferay service action.

http://proliferay.com/liferay-service-hook-override-liferay-service/

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You should either [include](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) the essential parts of the link (and keep the link for reference), or add this information as comment.